# ng-repeat changing position left to right

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have one problem with angular `ng-repeat` and bootstrap. I tried divide view on two parts left image, right description, but next line oposite, left description and right image. I would like something like picture below

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="{{item.image}}" alt="#"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="description">
          <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you using "items" in ng-repeat ? Dont see it used in the coode snippet above

Comment: Example http://jsfiddle.net/hstppbj8/182/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for odd or even iteration in the repeat loop and apply your class with either float left or right respectively.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="'img-left'">
      <div class="col-xs-6 img-holder">
        <img src=".." alt="#"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-holder">
        <div class="description">
          <p>........</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .img-left .img-holder{
    float:left;
    }
    .img-left .text-holder{
    float:right;
    }
```

you can handle even condition directly in CSS or like above.

Comment: Thank you nice answer, but I have to change float:left on float: right in img-holder and the same in text-holder because default in bootstrap img is to left

Comment: @V.R that's alright, you can add your class as required. It was just example.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. Using `ng-class` we check if the current index (`$index`) divided by 2 is zero then we add the float classes either `.left` or `.right`.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <div ng-repeat="val in arr">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-6" ng-class="$index % 2 === 0 ? 'left':'right'">
          {{val}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" ng-class="$index % 2 === 0 ? 'right':'left'">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we do have ng-class-odd and ng-class-even in Angular.

Comment: @jigargala This is new to me, Thanks, I didn't know this, but I'll stick to what I gave.

Comment: That's fine you can stick to your answer. it is all about best practices. we can avoid two ng-class conditions here and use one at the top and then use CSS for child div with the respected class.

Comment: @jigargala ok got it